# Lost custom settings upgrading Ubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: upgrade, interface, preferences

Argh. I went ahead and upgraded Ubuntu but didn't realize it wouldn't preserve my system settings - background, menus, system theme, preferences, system sound, settings, fonts, everything... I can't even run Scrivener. I didn't think to run backups or save whatever files you would save before inputting the command to upgrade in the terminal. Is there any hope to restore or should I just go ahead working on getting my preferred interface set up from scratch?
Edit: so weird. The reason I thought everything went back to the system default is that after upgrading to 21.04, it booted in cinnamon, instead of into plasmashell. I had problems and hit alt-F2 and typed "plasmashell" and all my old menus and settings just sprang up. I don't even have a very clear idea of what those two things are, tbh. Unfortunately now Dolphin isn't in the nice solid black theme I used to have - I meddled with system settings inside Cinnamon and it has remembered some of my changes. There is no option at bootup to choose which of these two (interfaces? whatever plasmashell and cinnamon are), but I guess I can just force it on when I need to.

Comment: It's super weird. There's a kind of dropdown at startup now, and it defaults to cinnamon, and if I remember to click it and select "plasma", then it boots properly into my usual way of running (plasmashell). But if not, cinnamon forks up the works and I need to reboot.

Comment: Could you give some more details on what exactly you want? I am not sure how you would get your old settings back, you will likely have to adjust them manually, but as for your difficulty with the desktop environments, do you want plasmashell or cinnamon? Seeing as you must have installed Ubuntu 21.04 with Cinnamon, the setting defaults are going to be Cinnamon. You should be able to set the defaults to plasmashell. [This](https://www.howtogeek.com/193129/how-to-install-and-use-another-desktop-environment-on-linux/#:~:text=How%20to%20Switch%20Between%20Desktop,choose%20your%20preferred%20deskt